# How can I receive mail on WordPress with contact 7 and Easy WP SMTP on localhost WAMP?

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, wamp, contact-form-7

I installed Contact 7 and Easy WP SMTP plugins on WP locally on WAMP server, but i can't receive mail when i write on contact form. 
I use yahoo SMTP host, and have this message when i test mail:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: 

 (0)SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.
```

[screenshot for Easy WP SMTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ1vK.jpg)

[screenshot for Easy Contact 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl1Xz.png)

Answer (score 0):

this could easily be an authentication problem. Test the credentials using something like [this](https://www.smtper.net/).